# Delegate on function which returns value in other thread

Tags: .net, vb.net, delegates

I'm sure it's a simple problem. I read from serial port some data and at some parse point, I need to update some statuslabel. Surprisingly, statuslabel is threadsafe... I didn't know...

Ok, but the statuslabel needs to include some combo text which appears to be not thread safe

statLabel1.Text = "Connected to " & cmbPort.text & ", found and happy"

So I tried to make a function to "Read Safe" from any component.text but I failed...

```
Private Delegate Function ControlGetTextDelegate(ByRef cmp As Control) As String
Public Function ControlGetText(ByRef cmp As Control) As String

    Dim s As String = ""

    ' control invoked from another thread ?
    If cmp.InvokeRequired Then ' YES, so call through delegate

        Dim dlg As New ControlGetTextDelegate(AddressOf ControlGetText)
        cmp.BeginInvoke(dlg, {cmp})

    Else ' NO, so call normally
        s = cmp.Text
    End If

    Return s

End Function
```

Can someone give a little help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're not assinging anything to `s` when `InvokeRequired = True`.

You can assign the result to `s` (you'll need to make that `Invoke` instead of `BeginInvoke`), but it might be better to invoke the event handler that you're calling this from instead. You didn't post that code, but it is basically the same idea -- test that `InvokeRequired` on the form, then call `BeginInvoke` for the event handler itself.

Comment: you rock :) thanks very much. I changed to s = cmp.Invoke(dlg, {cmp}) and works like a charm. In fact I tried but BeginInvoke don't allowed to return my value.

Comment: can you little explain what you said with better solution ?

Comment: `BeginInvoke` is asynchronous, so it returns an `IAsyncResult`. In your example you want `Invoke`. Or use `BeginInvoke` on the event handler.

Comment: @user1797147 The other solution would be to call to check `InvokeRequired` and then call `BeginInvoke` on the actual event handler, rather than this function. Then you're running all of your event handler code on the UI thread. There are lots of examples of doing this (mostly c#, probably).